# Collision detection between rectangles

Tags: c#

I have a Canvas with 2 System.Window.Shape.Rectangle on it that move around.

```
private void TimerAnimiere_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    zeichenfläche.Children.Clear();
    test.Animiere(timerAnimiere.Interval);
    test.Draw();
    test2.Animiere(timerAnimiere.Interval);
    test2.Draw();
    if (test.DetectCollision(test2.drawRect) == IntersectionDetail.Intersects)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The 2 Objects test and test2 are from my own Class and have a Rectangle(drawRect) included.
I would like to detect if they collide. So I wrote the following Method:

```
public override IntersectionDetail DetectCollision(Rectangle colidingObjekt)
{
    var testwert = this.drawRect.RenderedGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(colidingObjekt.RenderedGeometry);
    return testwert;
}
```

But the Problem is that it always returns that they Intersect even though when they aren't. 
I don't understand. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could use a debugger, set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect variables and see what's actually going on.

Comment: BTW: `zeichenfläsche` reads funny. Is this hessisch?

Comment: I did and looked into the RenderedGeometry object off the 2 Rectangles. There i mentioned that the Property off the Rect.X and Rect.Y are in both Objects equal 0. But the 2 Rectangles get parsed in correctly so I don't understand what i did wrong. zeichenfläsche is German and means drawing area.

Comment: I'm German, too. I do know `zeichenfläche` only 

Comment: My fault XD then it must be hessisch *cough*

Comment: Save the geometry objects into own variables and look into their details during debugging. If you find the failures, it's done. If you don't, you can still write your own method... Calculation of intersection of rectangles is not sooo hard.